# Tikz not working with {book} documentclass to draw graphs

Tags: graphs

I need to draw a graph in a document built with `\documentclass{book}`.
To do this I'm using the `tikz` package, but when I run the .tex file the nodes are all one above the other, no matter the distance I set.
This is the code I'm using:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance={50mm}, thick,  main/.style = {draw, circle}]                                
\node[main] (1) {$1$};
\node[main] (2) [right of=1] {$2$};
\node[main] (3) [right of=2] {$3$};
\node[main] (4) [below of=1] {$4$};
\node[main] (5) [right of=4] {$5$};
\node[main] (6) [right of=5] {$6$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

With `documentclass{article}` the code works fine, but I cannot use that documentclass.
Could you help me to understand why the package is not working? Do you know other solutions?

This is the code that I run:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{indentfirst}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{eucal}
\usepackage{eufrak}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphs.standard,quotes,arrows.meta}

\title{My Title}
\author{Me}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\input{doc1.tex}
\input{doc2.tex}

\end{document}
```

`doc2.tex` is the .tex file that contains the details of the graph I want to build.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of a code snippet.

Comment: I can't reproduce this, putting your code in between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` and using `\documentclass{book}\usepackage{tikz}` as the preamble everything works as expected.

Comment: I updated the question adding the code that I run. I've also tried to put the code in the same .tex file that I run, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with `book` vs. `article`, the problem here is the use of the `dvips` option for `graphicx`. Presumably you're not generating the PDF by first making a DVI-file, then using `dvips` to make a PostScript-file, and then `ps2pdf` to make a PDF.

In general, I think it's best to not specify the driver (such as `dvips`) for `graphicx`

TikZ actually loads `graphicx` for you, so just removing the line `\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}` will do. Test the example below with and without the commented line to see.

Unrelated: Note that the `right of=` syntax is considered deprecated, see e.g. [Difference between "right of=" and "right=of" in PGF/TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9386/difference-between-right-of-and-right-of-in-pgf-tikz)

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance={50mm}, thick,  main/.style = {draw, circle}]                                
\node[main] (1) {$1$};
\node[main] (2) [right of=1] {$2$};
\node[main] (3) [right of=2] {$3$};
\node[main] (4) [below of=1] {$4$};
\node[main] (5) [right of=4] {$5$};
\node[main] (6) [right of=5] {$6$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Now it works. Thank you!